# How to get current_user.id after signup in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to get id of user which successfully signup in devise registration.How can I do that?

Is it possible?

Comment: Why this question was voted down? Looks legit...

Answer (score 3):

You can get the ID of login user with `current_user.id` using Devise. If your devise is not set for `Confirmable` than user directly login after successfully signup. At this stage you can get id with `current_user.id`

Comment: But my devise is set with Confirmable. How I get now?

Comment: First you have to confirm the email address, then login with email and password. After only login you can get id of login user/

Comment: Isn't it possible to get before confirmation?

Comment: current_user helper is set only after you login to the system. So you have to first login.

Comment: Or alternatively, override the default devise registration controller and find the user by his/her email `User.find_by_email(params[:email])`.

Comment: `User.find_by(email: ...)` is the modern notation.

Comment: @haseeb what is the purpose of finding current_user id after signup? It would be helpful to give answer if you write your question in detail.

Comment: @GaneshKunwar after sign up user gives his company information. that's why i need his id

Comment: @haseeb you can make company information part of the signup form, can't you ?